# Mysql join with counting results in another table

Tags: mysql, select, join, count

I have two tables, one with ranges of numbers, second with numbers. I need to select all ranges, which have at least one number with status in (2,0). I have tried number of different joins, some of them took forever to execute, one which I ended with is fast, but it select really small number of ranges.

```
   SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS md_number_ranges.*
     FROM md_number_list
     JOIN md_number_ranges
       ON md_number_list.range_id = md_number_ranges.id
    WHERE md_number_list.phone_num_status NOT IN  (2, 0)
      AND md_number_ranges.reseller_id=1
 GROUP BY range_id
    LIMIT 10
   OFFSET 0
```

What i need is something like "select all ranges, join numbers where number.range_id = range.id and where there is at least one number with phone_number_status not in (2, 0).

Any help would be really appreciated.

Example data structure:

md_number_ranges:

```
id  |  range_start  |  range_end |  reseller_id 
 1  |     000001    |    000999  |       1
 2  |     100001    |    100999  |       2
```

md_number_list:

```
id  |   range_id    |  number    |  phone_num_status
 1  |       1       |  0000001   |       1 
 2  |       1       |  0000002   |       2
 3  |       2       |  1000012   |       0
 4  |       2       |  1000015   |       2
```

I want to be able select range 1, because it has one number with status 1, but not range 2, because it has two numbers, but with status which i do not want to select.

Comment: Is it possible to share table columns and some data?

Comment: yes, I wanted to, but not sure how to make tables here in stackoverflow editor

Comment: you may take a screenshot, and upload it as a picture.

Comment: I added example to my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell what you want, but perhaps this will do:

```
SELECT *
from   md_number_ranges m
join (
   SELECT md_number_ranges.id
        , count(*) as FOUND_ROWS
   FROM   md_number_list
   JOIN   md_number_ranges
     ON   md_number_list.range_id = md_number_ranges.id
   WHERE md_number_list.phone_num_status NOT IN  (2, 0)
     AND md_number_ranges.reseller_id=1
   GROUP BY range_id
   ) x
on x.id=m.id
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but this does not work for me, i got syntax error near SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Comment: I replaced SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with different variable name and it seems to work now, but still it will not select all results

Comment: If you mean you only get 10 rows, that's because of your `LIMIT` statement.  Otherwise I don't understand, sorry. And I'll revise the answer with a different column name; it's a reserved word.

Comment: No it was not caused by limit, it was my fault. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
FROM md_number_ranges r
    JOIN md_number_list l ON r.id = l.range_id
WHERE l.phone_num_status NOT IN (0,2)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6b482/2)